# Sum over abstract value

Tags: output-formatting

My plan is to write a sum over an index. Currently I write

```
Sum[f[OverTilde[q]], OverTilde[q] ∈ Subscript[l, i]]
```

but *Mathematica* always tells me that

> "The variable `OverTilde[q] \[Element]Subscript[l,i]` cannot be localized, so that it can be assigned to numerical values."

The key thing is that I do not need a numerical value -- this is an abstract function. How to remove the bug?

Comment: Vivian, Similarly to [your previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113989/27951), `Mathematica`'s main purpose is to do calculations, rather than to format input. Your input cannot be used reasonably in a calculation, so `Mathematica` won't like it if you try to evaluate it. I'd suggest that you NOT evaluate the cell, if your purpose is simply to produce typeset mathematical formulae. If you do want to run calculations, though, then the syntax you are using is simply incorrect for the `Sum` command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's what you want to achieve but if you want Mathematica to process your input while keeping the sum only as a symbol you may want to make it inactive (a new feature since version 10.0). Try:

```
Inactive[Sum][f[OverTilde[q]], OverTilde[q] ∈ Subscript[l, i]]
```

This way you can still use it as a part of a formula, or assign it to a variable, for example, but Mathematica won't try (and fail, as you found) to do the actual summation. It will do its other tasks like formatting and converting to boxes (`Subscript[x,1]` → x₁).

Note the uncommon structure of the command: the head is now composite itself, `Inactive[Sum]`, and takes arguments as usual, hence the successive `...][...` brackets. You will find similar constructs using, for example, `Derivative`.

Comment: By the way, **if** `Subscript[l, i]` is an actual set (entered as a list in MMA), the Mathematica way of iterating over it would be `Sum[f[OverTilde[q]], {OverTilde[q], Subscript[l, i]}]`. But that does not work if it is not.